# How can I align the full names in a list of acronyms?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, acronyms

I am using latex to write my thesis report and would like to generate list of abbreviation for same. I use the acrnonyms package to generate it. Following is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining} 
\acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output} 
\acro{RF }{Radio Frequency} 
\acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array} 
\acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error Rate} 
\acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining} 
\acro{CSI }{Channel State Information} 
\acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio} 
\acro{CDF }{Cumulative Distribution Function} 
\acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution Function} 
\acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

The above code does generate a list of acronyms, but the full names are not aligned under each other. Is there a way to arrange them?

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing the name of your longest acronym as an optional parameter to the acronym environment. In your case it would lead to the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[AWGN]
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining} \acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output} \acro{RF }{Radio
Frequency} \acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array} \acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error
Rate} \acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining} \acro{CSI }{Channel
State Information} \acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio} \acro{CDF }{Cumulative
Distribution Function} \acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution
Function} \acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

You get the following result:

[image]